# Theorem-like definition, without using upshape each time

Tags: fonts, theorems

How can I have theorems and lemmas stated in the default italic font, but definitions and examples in upright font, without having to type the `\upshape` command within each definition and example?  I use the following preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@begintheorem#1#2{\trivlist
%   \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2}]\itshape}
\item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #2.\ #1:}]\itshape}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{Lemma}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{Theorem}[Lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Example}[Lemma]{Example}
\newtheorem{Definition}[Lemma]{Definition}
```

The following code works:

```
\begin{Definition} \upshape 
Here's the definition. 
\end{Definition}
```

But it requires having to type `\upshape` each time I have a Definition or Example.  Can the preamble be modified so that I don't have to type `\upshape` each time?

Comment: Do you use a theorem management package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem`?

Comment: nope, not as of now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible approach is to use »[amsthm](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)« …

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{Lemma}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{Theorem}[Lemma]{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Definition}[Lemma]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Example}[Lemma]{Example}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Foo}
    \begin{Lemma}
      Lemma body
    \end{Lemma}

    \begin{Theorem}
      Theorem body
    \end{Theorem}

    \begin{Definition}
      Definition body
    \end{Definition}

    \begin{Example}
      Example body
    \end{Example}
\end{document}
```

… and another is to use »[ntheorem](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem)«.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Foo}
    \begin{Lemma}
      Lemma body
    \end{Lemma}

    \begin{Theorem}
      Theorem body
    \end{Theorem}

    \begin{Definition}
      Definition body
    \end{Definition}

    \begin{Example}
      Example body
    \end{Example}
\end{document}
```

The output is almost the same. Customization is shown in the respective manual.