# set \textstyle for one single tabbing invironment

Tags: tabbing

I have a `\tabbing` environment within a `\theorem` environment.
How can I have the text within this **single** `\tabbing` upright instead of italic?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{theorem}
    Some italic text.
    \begin{tabbing}
        Some non-italic \=text\\
        where I \>can use tabbing.
    \end{tabbing}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\textstyle` is a math mode primitive, so it's not clear at all what you want, since you can't really set text in `\textstyle`. Please edit your question and show us the code you are using and what the problem actually is.

Comment: Do you mean upright, instead of italic?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes.

Comment: It would be helpful for those trying to help you if you edit your question and provide a small, but complete, code example (beginning with `\documentclass`} that shows the problem.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: A question like this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142083/theorem-like-definition-without-using-upshape-each-time, might help.  Here, `amsthm` package is used with `\theoremstyle` to achieve upright or italic.  However, if you speak of only changing part of the style within the theorem to upright, the declaration for upright shape is `\upshape` and that for italic shape is `\itshape`.

Comment: I don't what to have each tabbing as upright, just this single on.

Comment: But I think I just have to add `\upshape` at the start of each row then?

Comment: If `\upshape` is in force before entering the `tabbing` environment, it will apply to all rows of the `tabbing`.  If it is invoked within the `tabbing` environment, it will only apply to its particular *scope*, which for `tabbing`, is a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands you are looking for are `\upshape` and `\itshape`.  For more information, [What is the origin of the family/series/shape distinction?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371931/what-is-the-origin-of-the-family-series-shape-distinction)

As I note in a comment about *scope*, if `\upshape` is in force before entering the `tabbing` environment, it will apply to all rows of the `tabbing`. If it is invoked within the `tabbing` environment, it will only apply to its particular *scope*, which for `tabbing`, is a single row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{theorem}
    Some italic text.
    \upshape\begin{tabbing}
        Some non-italic \=text\\
        where I \>can use tabbing.
    \end{tabbing}\itshape
    More text.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, thank you